# Add Current Page URL Before Anchor Link Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck utilizing a platform (Nationbuilder) that automatically adds the base tag in the header. It didn't until recently and now the dozens of pages with anchor links end up sending the user to the homepage.

I need to use jQuery to add the current page's url before the #anchor. The closest I can find is the following code, but I have no idea how to modify it so ONLY links with a href attribute starting with a # are modified:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/pageslug")
```

So I would like:

```
<a href="#anchorname"></a>
```

To be changed to:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/pageslug#anchorname"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS attribute starts with selector:

Instead of selecting `"a"`, select `'a[href^="#"]'` meaning "a tags with an href attribute starting with `#`.

So something like:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function(i,el){
    el.href = "http://www.example.com/pageslug" + el.hash;
});
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/G7sa8/)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to change the links to `http://www.example.com/pageslughttp://fiddle.jshell.net/3c2aB/show/#about` instead of `http://www.example.com/pageslug#about`. el.href returns the full, parsed url, while $(el).attr('href') gives just the value of the href attribute, as needed. @Novaugust's solution seems to work.

Comment: @Ketola you're absolutely correct, that was supposed to be `el.hash` and not `el.href` - nice catch will update.

Comment: [via](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22415526/1724139), use `el.getAttribute("href")` if you ever have to deal with relative hrefs that contain more than just a hash, ie `"/about"` -> `"example.com/about"`

Comment: If I wanted to get the path, I'd use `el.pathname`. That's also built in.

Comment: Thanks Ben! That was a HUGE time saver!

Answer (score 3):

One addition to what Benjamin said, you'll need to capture the current href for each of the anchors, which means you need a loop. So

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function(index, element){
    var $ele = $(element),
        oldHref = $ele.attr('href');
    $ele.attr('href', '//example.com/page'+ oldHref);
});
```

Comment: Benjamin added a loop, and his code's even prettier

Comment: Generally, you don't need to (and shouldn't) wrap native DOM objects when it's not beneficial, every `HTMLAnchorElement` ("a" tag) has a `.href` attribute on it and you can use it directly :)

Comment: Yeah, your solution is gorgeous. I was too wrapped up in jQuery ;)

Comment: However Benjamin's fiddle doesn't work on Chrome 33.0.1750.146. Your code seems to give expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/3c2aB/1/

Comment: Weird. I completely prefer his code. Why doesn't it work?  I figured that was a good enough question that I [asked it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415435/concatenating-a-href-via-jquery-versus-web-api)

Comment: @Novaugust I mistakenly used `.href` instead of `.hash` in both parts rather than just the left hand side of the assignment, that's why it didn't work :)

Comment: I was ignorant that `.href` always returned an absolute, which was why it looked good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('a').attr('href', window.location.pathname + this.attr('href'))
```