# Setting anchor href via jquery versus native dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From two of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414605/add-current-page-url-before-anchor-link-using-jquery/22414744) question I came up with a question of my own.

Given

```
 <a href="#example">
```

use jQuery to change teach anchor to

```
<a href="//example.com/page#example>
```

There were two nearly identical answers given:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function(index, element){
    var $ele = $(element),
        oldHref = $ele.attr('href');
    $ele.attr('href', '//example.com/page'+ oldHref);
});
```

and

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function(i,el){
    el.href = "http://www.example.com/pageslug" + el.href;
});
```

The one that wraps the native dom element to a jQuery object gives the expected result, whereas the one that uses the ".href" property does not. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3c2aB/))

What's going on with .href there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.href` returns the href property of the element, which is an absolute URL, while `attr('href')` returns whatever is in the attribute, that's the difference.

```
<a href="#test"></a>
```

-

```
element.href         // returns absolute URL, as in http://stackoverflow.com#test
$(element).prop('href') // jQuery version of the above, returns absolute URL

element.getAttribute('href') // returns the attributes value, as in #test
$(element).attr('href')      // jQuery version of getAttribute, returns #test
```